# How can i get tasks performed on a certain date?

Tags: c#, calendar

How can i display the task details performed within a particular date when i click on said date in the calendar control.

Example:

- I click on Jan 5 in the calendar and then i get the task performed on that date.

I am using C# and ASP.NET (2008)

Comment: Please repgrase your question: What do you want to do? What technologies/frameworks are you using?

Comment: @thiru: welcome to stackoverflow. Unfortunately, I don't follow your question. Can you please take some time to reword it so it is clearer? Once you do, it's likely the question will be reopened.

Comment: You'll need to be more specific.
What type of tasks, do you want to see them or get them performed, because in the body you ask for displaying them while in the title you ask to perform them...

Comment: if take example jan 5. jan 5 is a working day of a concern in that date i enter some working details and stored in data base now i want to retrive that data while click  jan 5 in clender control.

Answer (score 2):

store task with date in database. write select statement that has date parameter and return task on given parameter. Onclick event return data from executed procedure and display result.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a table with tasks and assigned dates, create a DataSet with a TableAdapter for said table, and use an ObjectDataSource on your page that takes the selected calendar day as a param and returns the rows to a GridView.